# ShapeFile with Z Co-ordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, sql-server, 3d

I have 3 shapefiles, two of them wihtout the Z Co-ordinates elevation but 1 of them has a Z co-ordinate elevation. I can load two ShapeFiles into my SQL Server Database which does not have Z Co-ordinates. But I am having issue loading the Z Co-ordinate file into the database.

I have been reading different forums and got a suggestion that I need to trim the Z coordinates(chnage 3D to 2D) to load into the database. I was just wondering how can I achieve this? Can anyone suggest free tools or any method to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

In ArcCatalog, create a new shp with all of the same properties as the problematic one, but do not check the [] will have Z coordinates box.
Then, use DataManagement/CopyFeatures to copy all of the features from the problem shp to the new one, and continue your analysis with the (2D) copy.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what tool is being used to load the shapefiles into MS SQL Server.

For [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) with the [MSSQLSpatial](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_mssqlspatial.html) driver, force 2D geometries using the command:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite \
    -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=.\MSSQLSERVER2008;database=geodb;trusted_connection=yes" \
    myshapes.shp -lco DIM=2
```